# Why it doesn't set DEBUG = True?

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I'm working in a Django project with a venv. My problem is the next one: I've configure DEBUG = TRUE in my code below, but it seems that setting is not loaded when django is starting and it launch this error: `You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.`

I think DEBUG is changed in the virtual environment because I debug my code and I found that DEBUG is false before starting the server

[image]

```
import django_heroku
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
]

PRIORITY_THIRD_PARTY_PASS = [
    'django_admin_env_notice',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_filters',
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'drf_yasg',
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'finalusers',
    'reports',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = PRIORITY_THIRD_PARTY_PASS + DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'circulo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django_admin_env_notice.context_processors.from_settings',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'circulo.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Mexico_City'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

LOGIN_URL = '/login'

ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "ENVIRONMENT NOT SET"
ENVIRONMENT_COLOR = "#000000"

OTP_TOTP_ISSUER = '{{ project_name }}'

if USE_TZ:

    CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE

CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')result_serializer


CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
redbeat_redis_url = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/1')
```

Comment: Is it overwritten by django_heroku.settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem:

I forgot to rename the name in the location of the configuration in the manage.py so the venv was not able to find the configuration and then accordingly he set the default configuration (DEBUG = False)